# How to explore web-based Google Play in another country?

Tags: android, country

if I go to play.google.com, it automatically recognizes my country and allow me to browse the apps for that country. I can change the language through the dropdown in the footer, or I can add &hl=code in the querystring...but that only changes the language...not the store content (the app lists and rankings remain the same)

I guess there must be some other querystring parameter or header parameter, because I'm sure Google devs don't use country-specific proxies or PCs located in locations in 50+ countries to see how the store appears there.

Any clue how this can be done?

Comment: I know this is their intent, and I know I can use the proxy (it's written in the question). Still, I'd like to know whther there is another, possibly undocumented, way (maybe the one they use internally to test the store from their local browser)

Comment: Use proxies, this is the accurate and best guaranteed way. Because if you use gl=ru you never know if their server will honor that later on or they might change API

Answer (score 93):

Looking for a solution to this exact problem brought me here, but unfortunately nobody gave the right answer. Here it is: Add the parameter gl=(countrycode).

For example, to see the list of top free business applications in your country, use this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS/collection/topselling_free

Adding gl=ru gives you the list for Russia:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS/collection/topselling_free?gl=ru

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. it also works when searching an app, e.g. verifying that chinese users can see my app or not

Comment: Works great, and very useful for [Chart pages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/PERSONALIZATION/collection/topselling_free?gl=uk).

Comment: Thank You So Much

Comment: Requested URL was not found on the server.

Comment: Not working anymore. I think google has removed all such links

Answer (score 68):

Here are list of nice clickable links for lazy people like me:

- https://play.google.com/?gl=al Albania
- https://play.google.com/?gl=dz Algeria
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ao Angola
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ag Antigua and Barbuda
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ar Argentina
- https://play.google.com/?gl=am Armenia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=aw Aruba
- https://play.google.com/?gl=au Australia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=at Austria
- https://play.google.com/?gl=az Azerbaijan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bs Bahamas
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bh Bahrain
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bd Bangladesh
- https://play.google.com/?gl=by Belarus
- https://play.google.com/?gl=be Belgium
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bz Belize
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bj Benin
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bo Bolivia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ba Bosnia and Herzegovina
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bw Botswana
- https://play.google.com/?gl=br Brazil
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bg Bulgaria
- https://play.google.com/?gl=bf Burkina
- https://play.google.com/?gl=kh Cambodia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=cm Cameroon
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ca Canada
- https://play.google.com/?gl=cv Cape Verde
- https://play.google.com/?gl=cl Chile
- https://play.google.com/?gl=co Colombia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=cr Costa Rica
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ci Cote d' Ivore
- https://play.google.com/?gl=hr Croatia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=cy Cyprus
- https://play.google.com/?gl=cz Czech Republic
- https://play.google.com/?gl=dk Denmark
- https://play.google.com/?gl=do Dominican Republic
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ec Ecuador
- https://play.google.com/?gl=eg Egypt
- https://play.google.com/?gl=sv El Salvador
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ee Estonia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=fj Fiji
- https://play.google.com/?gl=fi Finland
- https://play.google.com/?gl=fr France
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ga Gabon
- https://play.google.com/?gl=de Germany
- https://play.google.com/?gl=gh Ghana
- https://play.google.com/?gl=gr Greece
- https://play.google.com/?gl=gt Guatemala
- https://play.google.com/?gl=gw Guinea-Bissau
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ht Haiti
- https://play.google.com/?gl=hn Honduras
- https://play.google.com/?gl=hk Hong Kong
- https://play.google.com/?gl=hu Hungary
- https://play.google.com/?gl=is Iceland
- https://play.google.com/?gl=in India
- https://play.google.com/?gl=id Indonesia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ie Ireland
- https://play.google.com/?gl=il Israel
- https://play.google.com/?gl=it Italy
- https://play.google.com/?gl=jm Jamaica
- https://play.google.com/?gl=jp Japan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=jo Jordan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=kz Kazakhstan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ke Kenya
- https://play.google.com/?gl=kw Kuwait
- https://play.google.com/?gl=kg Kyrgyzstan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=la Laos
- https://play.google.com/?gl=lv Latvia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=lb Lebanon
- https://play.google.com/?gl=li Liechtenstein
- https://play.google.com/?gl=lt Lithuania
- https://play.google.com/?gl=lu Luxembourg
- https://play.google.com/?gl=mk Macedonia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=my Malaysia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ml Mali
- https://play.google.com/?gl=mt Malta
- https://play.google.com/?gl=mu Mauritius
- https://play.google.com/?gl=mx Mexico
- https://play.google.com/?gl=md Moldova
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ma Morocco
- https://play.google.com/?gl=mz Mozambique
- https://play.google.com/?gl=na Namibia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=np Nepal
- https://play.google.com/?gl=nl Netherlands
- https://play.google.com/?gl=an Netherlands Antilles
- https://play.google.com/?gl=nz New Zealand
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ni Nicaragua
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ne Niger
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ng Nigeria
- https://play.google.com/?gl=no Norway
- https://play.google.com/?gl=om Oman
- https://play.google.com/?gl=pk Pakistan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=pa Panama
- https://play.google.com/?gl=pg Papua New Guinea
- https://play.google.com/?gl=py Paraguay
- https://play.google.com/?gl=pe Peru
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ph Philippines
- https://play.google.com/?gl=pl Poland
- https://play.google.com/?gl=pt Portugal
- https://play.google.com/?gl=qa Qatar
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ro Romania
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ru Russia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=rw Rwanda
- https://play.google.com/?gl=sa Saudi Arabia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=sn Senegal
- https://play.google.com/?gl=rs Serbia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=sg Singapore
- https://play.google.com/?gl=sk Slovakia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=si Slovenia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=za South Africa
- https://play.google.com/?gl=kr South Korea
- https://play.google.com/?gl=es Spain
- https://play.google.com/?gl=lk Sri Lanka
- https://play.google.com/?gl=se Sweden
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ch Switzerland
- https://play.google.com/?gl=tw Taiwan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=tj Tajikistan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=tz Tanzania
- https://play.google.com/?gl=th Thailand
- https://play.google.com/?gl=tg Togo
- https://play.google.com/?gl=tt Trinidad and Tobago
- https://play.google.com/?gl=tn Tunisia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=tr Turkey
- https://play.google.com/?gl=tm Turkmenistan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ug Uganda
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ua Ukraine
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ae United Arab Emirates
- https://play.google.com/?gl=gb United Kingdom
- https://play.google.com/?gl=us United States (including Puerto Rico, American Samoa, Guam, Marshall Islands, Northern Mariana Islands, Palau and US Virgin Islands)
- https://play.google.com/?gl=uy Uruguay
- https://play.google.com/?gl=uz Uzbekistan
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ve Venezuela
- https://play.google.com/?gl=vn Vietnam
- https://play.google.com/?gl=ye Yemen
- https://play.google.com/?gl=zm Zambia
- https://play.google.com/?gl=zw Zimbabwe

If you spot any incorrect ones, feel free to edit of course.

You can also change language using the `hl` parameter, like this:

- https://play.google.com/?hl=ar

Comment: Could you list all the language codes? Country code and language code are different. I wonder what language code of Australia is. en_GB works for UK but en_AU doesn't work

Comment: The app control panel has a setting for all other countries (for countries not on the list - e.g. Swaziland) - what is the code to access these?

Answer (score 12):

You need to manipulate the *Google Play* URL. For example, for French use

```
https://play.google.com/store?gl=fr&tab=w8
```

for Spanish use

```
https://play.google.com/store?gl=sp&tab=w8
```

You should be able to swap out the country code (fr/sp/etc) using the codes discussed in the documentation on [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

If you would like to just change the language, but see the featured apps or rankings in your current country, use `hl` instead of `gl`

Comment: Yes, but this only changes the language and does not help if you want to see the featured apps or app rankings of another country.

Comment: There is a way to do this for currency?

Answer (score 11):

I would change both, the region `gl` and the language `hl`:

> https://play.google.com/?hl=vi&gl=vn

Using this example, you will visit the Vietnamese store - both as region and as language.

Answer (score 6):

You practically answered your own question already:
To force Google to display a page specific to a certain country you have to use a host that can send requests via IP ranges or providers that Google recognizes as being from that country. Proxies provide exactly that functionality.

Yes, you are right, developers or others in charge of testing Google services will likely not use proxies, though for a company that big providing a few test hosts in every country they operate in doesn't seem to be that big of a hassle.

If I had to implement a multinational service that provides content based on the location of the client I'd not try to obscure (as in [security by obscurity](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)) testing functionality by hiding it behind undocumented parameters. The cleaner and more obvious implementation of such a feature would be account-based functionalities.

- You are an ordinary user: I'll deliver content based on your location.
- You are signed in and the "Testers at Google" group: You see a setting to sort of "spoof" your location.

Actually, all systems I develop do feature extended debugging and testing functionalities, even on live hosts, but those features are never enabled or accessible to users at all. After all, that's what user groups are for.

Answer (score 6):

To do this, you could use a program called TorBrowser [Download Link Here From Cnet](http://download.cnet.com/Tor-Browser-Bundle/3001-2356_4-75660251.html?spi=e9808d57021895c18d5f185254a2b1d3&dlm=0) You can change around the settings a bit and select routing servers to go through only certain countries. The official website has some more documentation on this.

Comment: He was asking specifically for methods that don't involve using a proxy. TorBrowser does exactly that: It proxies your requests through an "onion-shaped" network.

Comment: It never asks for a method that is specifically anti-proxy. The plain answer is: you can't. That is, without breaking into Google's servers and viewing it that way. The proxy is the only way. Quote him on where he asks on anyway not using a proxy.

Comment: Very well, I'll quote: "... **some other querystring parameter or header** ... **don't use** country-specific **proxies**...". Then on 10/24, ten days before your answer, he comments on his own question "no...still **using proxies**". One might very well get the impression that he knows how to proxy his requests and did before your answer. Yes, the conclusion is, that you can't use a country specific preview. Coincidentally I came to that conclusion on 10/27.

Comment: @Alex You are paraphrasing that. Read it in context. He is stating that the devs don't use country specific proxies. Let me get my quote: "I guess there must be some other querystring parameter or header parameter, because I'm sure Google devs don't use country-specific proxies"

What I want to know is, why are you arguing with me? There really is no point to.

Comment: There's not a lot to paraphrase if someone asks for a solution other than proxying and answers with "no...still using proxies" when asked if a solution was found. Your answer is flawed as it mentions TorBrowser, which is a network of proxies and thus suggests to proxy requests, which is his current solution as can be seen (again without paraphrasing, misinterpreting or guessing anything) by the above comment he made days before you gave your answer. This is stackoverflow, a place to talk, argue and give answers, and discussing an answer is the reason the comment system exists.

Comment: Alex is correct that it doesn't answer the question as literally stated.  However, the OP states that he is still using proxies, so it does seem helpful to provide a free way to obtain a proxy in a number of different locations.  So Tux does seem to be providing information that addresses the OP's needs, even if that information does not answer the question per se.

Answer (score 1):

How You can See Top Trending apps in different Cattegorry You no need to use vpn or any other approach it an Easy way follow these Steps.

Very First:Logout your gmail account if it is login then start

1. let see here in the screen shots first look normally play store as in screen shot one:
   [image]

2.you can select any category here you wants to see there trending apps in different country and i select entertainments.
[image]

3.here you are looking top free entertainment options click on see more
[image]

4.you are looking top free entertainment but until not in different country now we use some syntax in url to find out this categorytop trending in different countries attention here in URL
[image]

5:the URL you are looking is here

https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ENTERTAINMENT/collection/topselling_free

you have to add something in plus to see like    ?gl=us     here us refer to America and au to Australasia and UK to England etc

https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ENTERTAINMENT/collection/topselling_free?gl=us

[image]

6.in screen shot 6 am looking all the apps in entertainment category in us

i hope you understand

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested adding `&hl=[language_code]` to the end of url and then have seen content and comments written in that language. Please  try this.

In previous answers the parameter name was used as `gl` instead of `hl` (possibly a typo).

Comment: It is not a typo, gl and hl are different parameters.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I have found to use Tor Browser.
You should set country code:

http://www.wikihow.com/Set-a-Specific-Country-in-a-Tor-Browser

For country codes:

http://www.b3rn3d.com/blog/2014/03/05/tor-country-codes/