# How to access android play store for all countries?

Tags: android, proxy, google-play, google-play-services, web-testing

I am doing macro to extract android apps information form google play store. My client require all android apps details in the world. I am staying in India since i could not access other country apps.

Kindly help me to access google play apps for all country.

I am using seleinum for scraping.

Answer (score 5):

By searching the internet about your problem, I found that you you can access other Countries Google Play Store with a VPN App.

By checking this [page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2155761), you will see the basic instructions oh how to do this.

Also you can try the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825318/how-to-explore-web-based-google-play-in-another-country), by simple adding the parameter `gl=(countrycode)` in the URL.

For example: 
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS/collection/topselling_free`

by adding **gl=ru** gives you the play store for Russia:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS/collection/topselling_free?gl=ru
```